# Frameset won't print in Chrome since update

Tags: google-chrome, printing, frame, print-preview

Anybody else having issues printing from sites with Framesets in Chrome since last week's update?
e.g https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_frame_cols

The print preview is blank (where the frames should be). Works fine in Edge.

Comment: This appears to be working fine in Chrome 79.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am experiencing the same issue.  Seems to have started with Chrome version  77.0.3865.90 (possibly earlier).  The same web pages containing framesets do print with Firefox.

A workaround is to select the entire page using ctrl-A and then ctrl-P (to print).  This will print what ever is selected on the page.  But the users I support want to know why their application pages won't print as it used to.